# cannot install $ npm i mini-css-extract-plugin. What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, webpack

This is the ERROR. I use visual studio code with gitBash.

```
$ npm i mini-css-extract-plugin
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: lesson-54-intro-webpack@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^4.39.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from mini-css-extract-plugin@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm ERR!   mini-css-extract-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Smith\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Smith\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-19T13_12_04_740Z-debug.log
```

This is my package JSON file. What could be wrong here?
How to match versions?

{
"name": "lesson-54-intro-webpack",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"dev": "webpack-dev-server",
"build": "webpack"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
"autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"css-loader": "^3.1.0",
"file-loader": "^4.1.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"precss": "^4.0.0",
"style-loader": "^0.23.1",
"webpack": "^4.39.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
},
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.19.0"
}
}

Comment: those are literally the same thing.  `npm i` is just an alias for `npm install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See the edit below.

As the error says the webpack version not matched try either:

- upgrade `lesson-54-intro-webpack` package
- downgrade `mini-css-extract-plugin`

---

**Edit:** based on your `package.json` content

You need to upgrade your `webpack` version to version 5

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QXod8eNzXyBdS7G48IOYBhR6N-wUG0Hb/view?usp=sharing
This is my package JSON file. 
What could be wrong here?

Comment: Please add it to you question

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here. How you add code without details. I can't add. 
This message is displayed:  " It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details "

Comment: It’s OK, welcome aboard, as I can see you’ve already added the package json

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I added. But it is not correct to output. Not readable. If done through ```console ```, then this message is displayed: " It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details "

Comment: This is syntax highlighting read [StackOverflow - syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and set the language to `json` rather than `console`, it may help

Comment: Elaborate the question so you won’t get this error

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please tell me,  is it mandatory to use miniCssExtractPlugin or not?

Comment: What do you need to do? Is this part of some tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I am doing a small project based on the tutorial. I wanted to know if it's worth using miniCssExtractPlugin in the future?

Comment: I don’t know this plugin, if my answer helped you don’t forget to mark it as solved 

Comment: yes of course I will not forget. Now I will try to update webpack.

Comment: Hey! Yes. Thanks

Comment: I put a green checkmark. Does this mean that the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, have a great day